# Removing unwanted line breaks and whitespaces in PHP - after scraping page using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, whitespace, line-breaks, removing-whitespace

I am using simple_html_dom.php library to scrape zxing QR decoder.

I get the ID of the QR code like this.

```
 $html = file_get_html($link_address); 

 //link_address holds the zxing decoder address.  
 //e.g of address: http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http://example.com/file.jpg   

 foreach($html->find('pre') as $e)
 $s= $e->outertext;
 $x = 'https://example.com?id='.$s;
```

The problem is that if I echo $x, it's as follows:

```
 http://example.com?id=

 1cOXkdnDtjNf
```

Where 1cOXkdnDtjNf is my decoded content.

The problem is that there are 2 line breaks above and below 1cOXkdnDtjNf.

I tried to remove white spaces and line breaks but the line breaks stayed.

```
 $str =  trim($x, "\x00..\x1F"); 
 $str = str_replace("\r", "", $str);
 $str = str_replace("\n", "", $str);
 $str = str_replace(array("\r","\n"), "", $str);
```

The line breaks remain. I think it's due to for each scraper.

Comment: Maybe the line breaks are br tags? Right click -> View source code and your will see it!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks +Rizier123 It was not break tags but pre tags that caused the breaks. I solved it using:

```
 $str = str_replace("<pre>", "", $str);
 $str = str_replace("</pre>", "", $str);
```

That sorted out the issue.

+Rizier123's comment prompted me to look at the source of the output and discover the pre tags.